# What is the Gravitational potential energy of two masses?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the gravitational potential energy. Suppose I have two masses $m$ and $M$ rotating around one another. Theres the gravitational force between them $F=-G\frac{mM}{r^2}$ and there's the potential energy $U=-G\frac{mM}{r}$.

Is the potential energy here the energy of both masses? of only one of them and the other one has the exact same energy? What is the total energy and is it easier to express with effective energy/center of mass system?

What is the energy of each mass and what is the energy of the entire system?

Answer (score 1):

Potential energy is said to be of the $m-M$ system since it is defined as the work done against the gravitational force to take the masses from $+\infty$ to a distance $r$. Since the masses tend to move towards each other gravitationally, that work is negative for an external being to move them close to each other *slowly*. The force between the masses is mutual by Newton's third law.

Comment: so can I look at the energy in the system of only one of the masses? and the energy of each mass is $U$ and together they have $2U$? (I think I'm wrong saying that)

Comment: As for potential energy, Nope! As for their mass energies$(E=mc^2)$, yes!

Comment: Understood, what about the effective energy and COM energy?

Comment: Energy and Mass are equivalent by the famous $E=mc^2$ equation. Both the masses have their mass energy.

Comment: To answer your main question, the potential energy of the $m-M$ system is $U=-\frac{GMm}{r}$, not of only $m$ or $M$.

Comment: COM energy is different for both if their center of masses are being considered individually. It is the same for the $m-M$ system if the COM of $m-M$ system is being considered to move through space(galaxy), just like potential energy. What is effective energy?

Comment: $U_{eff}=\frac{L^2}{2mr^2}-\frac{GmM}{r}$  where $L$ is the angular momentum (of both masses? of one? I don't know). and why does this include only 4m$ and not $M$ as well (in the denominator)

Comment: So what are those energies of COM?

Comment: Please avoid extended discussions in the comments. You can post these questions separately.

Answer (score 0):

The potential energy is always defined of system.

For example when we say when you raise a block of mass m by hieght h it's potential energy increase. What we mean by that is that combined potential energy of earth and block system. Suppose if there was no earth and you raise the block by hieght h then  the  change in potential energy is 0.

As the energy is stored between mutual gravitational field and in the above case that is absent.

Comment: so in the total energy even though we should include the kinteic energy (including rotational) energy of earth we say it's negligible?

Comment: I am only talking about gravitational potential energy.  For an observer outside the earth , the earth possess rotational and kinetic energy.

Comment: so in a frame inside earth and outside earth the energy is different (in one earth does not move)?

Comment: Yes. Kinetic energy is a frame dependent quantity as velocity is frame dependent.

Comment: Could you also answer the second part and explain how is the effective potential energy $U_{eff}=\frac{L^2}{2mr^2}-\frac{GmM}{r}$ used here and why does it only include $m$ and not $M$ (and what is $L$ in the angular momentum here?)

Comment: r is the distance of of mass m from M.and distance of mass M is from mass M is 0